# node js express framework cant start npm

Tags: node.js, express

**I have the following error:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program
   Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program
   Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js', 1 verbose cli  
   'start' ] 2 info using npm@3.10.10 3 info using node@v6.11.3 4
   verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ] 5 info
   lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~prestart: expresswebsite@0.0.0 6 silly
   lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart,
   continuing 7 info lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~start:
   expresswebsite@0.0.0 8 verbose lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~start:
   unsafe-perm in lifecycle true 9 verbose lifecycle
   expresswebsite@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;G:\Project\nodejs\project1\expresswebsite\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program
   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
   Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
   Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
   Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
   Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
   SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin;C:\Users\Rocky\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program
   Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Rocky\AppData\Roaming\npm 10
   verbose lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~start: CWD:
   G:\Project\nodejs\project1\expresswebsite 11 silly lifecycle
   expresswebsite@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/www' ] 12
   silly lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1 
   signal: null 13 info lifecycle expresswebsite@0.0.0~start: Failed to
   exec start script 14 verbose stack Error: expresswebsite@0.0.0 start:
   `node ./bin/www` 14 verbose stack Exit status 1 14 verbose stack    
   at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16) 14
   verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 14 verbose stack    
   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7) 14 verbose stack     at
   ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program
   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14) 14 verbose
   stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 14 verbose stack     at
   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) 14 verbose stack     at
   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16) 14 verbose stack     at
   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
   15 verbose pkgid expresswebsite@0.0.0 16 verbose cwd
   G:\Project\nodejs\project1\expresswebsite 17 error Windows_NT
   6.3.9600 18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
   "start" 19 error node v6.11.3 20 error npm  v3.10.10 21 error code
   ELIFECYCLE 22 error expresswebsite@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www` 22
   error Exit status 1 23 error Failed at the expresswebsite@0.0.0 start
   script 'node ./bin/www'. 23 error Make sure you have the latest
   version of node.js and npm installed. 23 error If you do, this is
   most likely a problem with the expresswebsite package, 23 error not
   with npm itself. 23 error Tell the author that this fails on your
   system: 23 error     node ./bin/www 23 error You can get information
   on how to open an issue for this project with: 23 error     npm bugs
   expresswebsite 23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their
   info via: 23 error     npm owner ls expresswebsite 23 error There is
   likely additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please restructure your question properly.

Comment: can not start npm

Comment: can we see the codes you're trying to run, so that we can know exactly where the bug is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

May be npm installed in 2 locations globally!

1. Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
2. AppData\Roaming\npm

Firstly, remove all npm completely including folders, find npm config file and remove it and remove node.js program. Secondly, make sure you have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable for your operating system type(32 or 64 bit). Lastly install latest version of node.js. Hope your problem will be fixed.